# PHP - Converting paragraph into bullet points

Tags: php

I am writing a small code where i want to convert an entire paragraph into bullet points. So basically, after every `.` a new bullet should start. How cold this be achieved in PHP?

Comment: So basically every `.` is not end of a paragraph!

Comment: sorry...i am a newbie in php language and got very little help on the internet while searching for similar issue..i could not come up with anythong on this so far...!

Comment: No, i have one big paragraph...for which i want to convert its every line into bullet points...

Comment: what is the purpose using php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$paragraph = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."

$lines = str_replace(".", "<li>", $paragraph);
echo "<ul>";
echo $lines;
echo "<ul>";
```

Answer (score 2):

try like this :use `explode` to make all possible array then you can use `array_filter` to remove empty values.

```
<?php 
$str="hi.hello.how.";
$arr=explode('.',$str);
echo "<ul><li>" . implode("</li><li>", array_filter($arr)) . "</li></ul>"

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a generic question asking "do this for me", this is all I'm going to show you. You'll have to figure out the rest.

```
$elements = explode(".", $string);

echo "<ul><li>" . implode("</li><li>", $elements) . "</li></ul>"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the explode function of PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Here is a example code:

```
<?php
$s = 'asdf. asdffff. asdfasfda.';
echo 's = ' . $s . '</br>';

$V = explode(".", $s);

echo '<ul>';
foreach($V as $x) {
  echo '<li>' . $x . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';

?>
```